# Objective C- Adding an object to an array, whilst mutating that object

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety, nsarray

In objective C, is it thread safe to add an object to an array (all processing/mutating/enumeration of this array occurs on its own single thread), whilst the object itself could potentially be mutated on a different thread?

When adding an object to an array, am I simply passing in a memory reference, and changes to the actual object will not cause issues at this point? Or will mutating that object on a different thread at the same time as adding it to an array result in a crash?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's safe. The array only cares about storing a reference to the object. Any changes to the object itself are totally invisible to the array. Of course if one thread reads myObject = myArray [i] then that thread must be aware that the contents of the object could change at any time.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I've spent the last couple of days building a co-ordinator class for threading in my app, assuming what you said, but suddenly panicked, as this point is critical.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is thread safe.

- To make thread safe array or any object, you must create object with property list "atomic".
  By this you will ensure that one thread will have access to your object / array and app won't crash.
- If you are storing object reference in array, then mutating the object values won't crash. As array is pointing to objects, but all objects must be atomic whose reference you have stored in array. To achieve thread safe.

Comment: "Atomic" adds very little value in multithreaded code. It may avoid certain crashes, but it doesn't avoid much more severe logic errors. If two threads modify an atomic property, you still don't know which thread "wins".